# TagHelpers add custom class for LabelTagHelper based on validation attribute [Required]

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, tag-helpers

In Core MVC there is anew concept as Tag helpers.

We could previously create custom html helpers to attach some classes based on the validation data annotations such as [Required].

As TagHelpers arq quite new area I cannot find anough resources to achieve the following:

here is the view model:

```
    [Required]
    public Gender Gender { get; set; }
```

view:

```
<label class="control-label col-md-3 required" asp-for="Gender"></label>
```

css:

```
.required:after {
content: "*";
font-weight: bold;
color: red;
}
```

output:
[image]

But I don't want to manully add the required css class in the label. Somehow I shoudl be able to extend the LabelTagHelper to read model data annotations and if it has the [Required] then add required class in the label element.

Thanks,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yup, you can extend this pretty easily by inheriting from the `LabelTagHelper` class and adding in your own class to the attribute list first.

```
[HtmlTargetElement("label", Attributes = "asp-for")]
public class RequiredLabelTagHelper : LabelTagHelper
{
    public RequiredLabelTagHelper(IHtmlGenerator generator) : base(generator)
    {
    }

    public override Task ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        if (For.Metadata.IsRequired)
        {
            CreateOrMergeAttribute("class", "required", output);
        }

        return base.ProcessAsync(context, output);
    }

    private void CreateOrMergeAttribute(string name, object content, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        var currentAttribute = output.Attributes.FirstOrDefault(attribute => attribute.Name == name);
        if (currentAttribute == null)
        {
            var attribute = new TagHelperAttribute(name, content);
            output.Attributes.Add(attribute);
        }
        else
        {
            var newAttribute = new TagHelperAttribute(
                name,
                $"{currentAttribute.Value.ToString()} {content.ToString()}",
                currentAttribute.ValueStyle);
            output.Attributes.Remove(currentAttribute);
            output.Attributes.Add(newAttribute);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I will try soon and accept the answer. It looks like it will work. Thanks

Comment: Yeap this works perfect. it is worth mentioning that once the custom tag helper is created it must be referenced in _ViewImports.cshtml file to work. something like:  @addTagHelper "*, WebApplicaiton.Web"

Comment: I realize this is a bit old however you might want to change `var attribute = new TagHelperAttribute("class", content);` to `var attribute = new TagHelperAttribute(name, content);` as this is susposed to be attribute name agnostic the coded `class` name seems incorrect to me.Otherwise +1 for me.

Answer (score 2):

For answer by Will Ray, I'd like to make a change to the override `ProcessAsync` as:

```
public override Task ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)

{     

     var isRequired = For.Metadata.ValidatorMetadata.Any(x => 
                         x.GetType().Name.Equals("RequiredAttribute"));
     if (isRequired)
     {
          CreateOrMergeAttribute("class", "required", output);
     }

     return base.ProcessAsync(context, output);
}
```

Since `For.Metadata.IsRequired` is always true for boolean properties.

Comment: not only boolean properties, but all value type properties

Answer (score 0):

As the treatment for Value and Reference types is different, the following code could help:

```
public override async Task ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context,TagHelperOutput output)
{
    await base.ProcessAsync(context, output);

    if (RequiredAttributeExists(For.Metadata))
    {
        output.AddClass("required", HtmlEncoder.Default);
    }
}

private static bool RequiredAttributeExists(ModelMetadata metaData)
{
    if (metaData.ModelType.IsValueType)
    {
        return metaData.ValidatorMetadata.Any(x => x is RequiredAttribute);
    }
    else // not value type
    {
        return metaData.IsRequired;
    }
}
```