# asp-validation-for triggering on get .net core

Tags: asp.net, validation, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a .NET Core app that the validation is triggering once the page is returned from the get. I have a view model, and I'm not sure why the validation is already triggered once I receive a response.

Here is my model and markup

```
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

    namespace MusicianProject.Models.ViewModels
    {
        public class RegisterViewModel
        {
            [Required(ErrorMessage ="First name is required.")]
            [Display(Name ="First Name")]
            [StringLength(25, ErrorMessage = "First name must be less than 25 characters.")]
            public string FirstName { get; set; }

            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Last name is required")]
            [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
            [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Last name must be less than 50 characters.")]
            public string LastName { get; set; }

            [Required]
            [EmailAddress]
            [Display(Name = "Email")]
            public string Email { get; set; }

            [Required]
            [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} and at max {1} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
            [DataType(DataType.Password)]
            [Display(Name = "Password")]
            public string Password { get; set; }

            [Required]
            [DataType(DataType.Password)]
            [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
            [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
            public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

        }
    }
```

And here is the register view that is returned.

```
@model MusicianProject.Models.ViewModels.RegisterViewModel

<div class="container">
    <form asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Register" method="post">

        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="FirstName"></label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" asp-for="FirstName" />
                <span asp-validation-for="FirstName">First name is required.</span>
            </div>


            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="LastName"></label>
                <input class="form-control" asp-for="LastName" />
                <span asp-validation-for="LastName">Last name is required.</span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Email"></label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" asp-for="Email" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Email">Email is required.</span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Password"></label>
                <input asp-for="Password" type="password" id="password" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Password">Password is required.</span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ConfirmPassword"></label>
                <input asp-for="ConfirmPassword" type="password" id="confirm-password" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="ConfirmPassword">Confirm password is required</span>
            </div>


            <div class="btn-group text-center">
                <button class="btn btn-default">Sign up!</button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </form>
</div>
```

I have two register methods, post and get. Here is what I have.

```
 [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Register()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult Register(RegisterViewModel rvm)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }

            return View();
        }
```

and when I navigate to the route in my browser, here is what I get.

[image: My signup form]

Answer (score 1):

Simply remove all the text inside of the `<span asp-validation-for>` tags in your view.

The tag helpers will inject the text for you when there is a validation error, depending on what your annotations have set. The way you have it now forcibly prints those messages.

Comment: I tried doing that and if I put a class on those spans, making them red, they are still showing. I'm using bootstrap so the class I'm putting on them is text-danger, and still shows the red outline. Is there a way to control the class through data annotations?

Comment: @destructi6n Could you show me an example of what one of the `span`s looks like after you made the change?

Comment: it looks like this. 
`<span asp-validation-for="Password"></span>`

Comment: @destructi6n You can control the class, but it would require a custom tag helper that extends the ASP one. The `text-danger` class should only be making the text red, not making a red outline. Perhaps this is an issue with some custom CSS rules?

Comment: do you know if there is any conditional way to change it? I'll look into resources on how to make my own tag helpers. Is it possible to make your own tag helper that works client side?

Comment: @destructi6n [Here is a very similar scenario](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41113568/4270650) which would give you a good starting point. You'd be doing the same thing, but for the validation tag helper.

Comment: thanks! I created a tag helper, but I can't manage to hit a break point, do I have to do anything besides declare it in the viewimports?

Comment: @destructi6n I think you may be at a point where you'll want to ask a new question. The only guess I have is that you may need to override the non-async `Process` method instead. To be sure that your custom helper is being used at all, point a breakpoint in the constructor.

Comment: I added a new question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41134362/custom-tag-helper-debugging) if you want to look