# Custom Tag helper debugging

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, tag-helpers

I'm trying to test a new tag helper that I'm trying to create. I've stumbled into a shortcoming of the new .net core validation and cannot change the class post validation. So if I wanted to give my errors a red background, the span is always there and won't change. So, I've decided to make my own tag helper. the problem is I can't seem to get it to work or trigger. I can't even get it to hit a break point. Here is what I have for a tag helper so far.

```
namespace MusicianProject.TagHelpers
{
    // You may need to install the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime package into your project
    [HtmlTargetElement("invalid-class",  Attributes = "validation-class")]
    public class ValidateClassTagHelper : TagHelper
    {
        public ValidateClassTagHelper(IHtmlGenerator generator) 
        {

        }
        public override Task ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
        {


            return base.ProcessAsync(context, output);
        }


        public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
        {

            output.Attributes.Add("class", "test");
            var attr = context.AllAttributes;


        }
    }
}
```

and here is the usage in my register view.

```
<div class="container">

    <form asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Register" method="post">

        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="FirstName"></label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" asp-for="FirstName" />
                <span asp-validation-for="FirstName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="LastName"></label>
                <input class="form-control" asp-for="LastName" />
                <span asp-validation-for="LastName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Email"></label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" asp-for="Email" />
                <span validation-class="alert alert-danger" invalid-class="test" asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Password"></label>
                <input asp-for="Password" type="password" id="password" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Password" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ConfirmPassword"></label>
                <input asp-for="ConfirmPassword" type="password" id="confirm-password" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="ConfirmPassword" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>


            <div class="btn-group text-center">
                <button class="btn btn-default">Sign up!</button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </form>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{ await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial"); }
}
```

And yes I have register in my _ViewImports.cshtml file, the projects assembly name.

```
@using MusicianProject
@using MusicianProject.Models
@addTagHelper "*, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers"
@addTagHelper "*, MusicianProject"
```

Now I'm not sure if placement of certain files matters, but my _ViewImports.cshtml file is located within my views folder root (src/Views/_ViewImports.cshtml), and my tag helpers have their own folder in the root (src/TagHelpers/*).

What did I miss and how can I correct it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 2 issues

1- The `HtmlTargetElement` is the name of the tag where this tag helper can be used, ex: span, div, table ...
2- You didn't use the tag helper in your code, accordingly, it will never get fired. it is not applied by default to all the tags specified in the `HtmlTargetElement`, you should call it by adding the `validate-class` attribute to the span tag.

To know more about tag helpers, please check this link https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/msgulfcommunity/2015/06/17/developing-custom-tag-helpers-in-asp-net-5/

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly your problem is that your breakpoint doesn't get hit. That problem lies here:

```
[HtmlTargetElement("invalid-class",  Attributes = "validation-class")]
```

The first parameter of HTMLTargetElement is the tag you are targeting, so in your case that would be "span". You entered a class name there.

This way at least your breakpoints will get hit and from there I'm sure you'll figure out the rest.